# I need to solve a equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Tags: group-theory

I need to solve the equation $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = 0$  in:

$(i)$ $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

$(ii)$ $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

$(iii)$ $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$

$(iv)$$\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

I don't know how to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Bruteforce it maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_2$:

You can check that if you put $x= 0$, the left-hand side amounts to $1$, which doesn't equal $0$, but if you put $x= 1$, the left-hand side amounts to $6$, which is congruent to $0 \mod 2$.

Therefore, in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the only solution is $x=1$.

$\mathbb{Z}_3$:

You can check that if you put $x= 0$, the left-hand side amounts to $1$, which is not congruent to $0 \mod 3$. If you put $x=1$, the left-hand side amounts to $6$, which is congruent to $0 \mod 3$; and if you put $x = 2$, the left-hand side amounts to $63$, which is congruent to $0 \mod 3$.

Therefore, in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the solutions are $x=1$ and $x = 2$.

Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, the only solution is $x=3$, and in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks Saaqib. Just a comment, following your previous reasoning I think that in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ there's a solution ($x=4$).

Comment: @gobaldia yes, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x^6-1=(x-1)(x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$.

So, the solutions of $x^6-1=0$ contain the solutions of $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1=0$.

Except for the case $\mathbb Z_4$ (which is not a domain), the solutions of $x^6-1=0$ that are different from $x=1$ are exactly the solutions of $x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1=0$.
Fermat's little theorem is useful here.